# append element to the end of each arrow in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

If i have an numpy array like:

```
x= [[3, 3], [2, 2]]
```

I want to add an element -1 to the end of each the rows to be like this:

```
x= [[3, 3, -1], [2, 2, -1]]
```

any simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be with [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) -

```
np.insert(x,x.shape[1],-1,axis=1)
```

We can also use [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) -

```
np.column_stack((x,[-1]*x.shape[0]))
```

Sample run -

```
In [161]: x
Out[161]: 
array([[0, 8, 7, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 8, 6, 8],
       [3, 4, 7, 0, 2]])

In [162]: np.insert(x,x.shape[1],-1,axis=1)
Out[162]: 
array([[ 0,  8,  7,  0,  1, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  8,  6,  8, -1],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  0,  2, -1]])

In [163]: np.column_stack((x,[-1]*x.shape[0]))
Out[163]: 
array([[ 0,  8,  7,  0,  1, -1],
       [ 0,  1,  8,  6,  8, -1],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  0,  2, -1]])
```

Comment: Very simple and elegant!

Comment: I tried np.insert(x,x.shape[1],-1,axis=1), and it worked fine. Thank you Divakar :)